# What is the magnetic-equivalent field of moving quark color charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, color-charge

A moving electric charge induces a magnetic field. What kind of field is induced by a moving (quark) color-charge?

Are there 3 kinds of color-magnetic fields? How would they interact with color-current carrying wires?

Can color charge-fields radiate?

Comment: Yes, there are color-electric and color-magnetic fields. But it's not that useful in practice to think about them that way because of confinement. There isn't a classical limit where you recover something like 3 copies of E&M (for the 3 colors).

Comment: Color confinement kind of destroys any analogy to electromagnetism here on any length scale above a femtometer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, since it's not reality, you can look at a classical version of an SU(3) field where the magnetic field with color $a$ satisfies:

$$ \vec \nabla \times \vec B^a=\partial_t\vec{E^a}+\vec{J^a}+gC^a_{bc}A^b_0 \vec{E^c}-gC^a_{bc}\vec{A^b}\times\vec {B^c}$$

where $abc$ label the color indices, $C^c_{ab}$ is the SU(3) structure constants, and $\vec E$, $\vec B$, $\vec J$, $\vec A$ are color analogs of the usual EM quantities.

So there is a displacement current, a color current, and nonlinear & non-abelian terms that mix in the fields with different colors.

Details can be found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0607203.pdf.